# Android Build and Obfuscate Libraryproject

Tags: android, ant, build, proguard, build.xml

I have an android library project. I want to build this project into a .jar I think and put this jar into my `/full` and my `/lite` Project. Before doing this I want to obfuscate the library project.
Is this possible? 
Before it was a library project I had a working build.xml to build the application out of this. This build.xml does not work for the library project.

Thanks and best regards,
Till

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard will obfuscate your code. Just repackage and then obfuscate the result.

Comment: Actually, Proguard handles a lot of calls through Reflection: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/introduction.html.  If you still run into an issue, just use -keepclass for the class you call dynamically.

Comment: The Android build process with ProGuard enabled will indeed obfuscate your projects including the library. Obfuscating a library alone is possible (cfr. ProGuard manual), but far less effective, since its public API has to be preserved.

Comment: If it's your library, just drop it into your App's code base and obfuscate everything at once.